# libvirt: error : unable to set AppArmor profile

Tags: virtual-machine, libvirt

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8o5DOf-_w-w) tutorial on how to GPU passthrough, however when I get to about 6:43 mark, where you press the **Begin Installation** button, I get this following error:

```bsh
Unable to complete install: 'internal error: Process exited prior to exec: libvirt:  error : unable to set AppArmor profile 'libvirt-5d739005-01d9-4c7c-9b41-bb3e3486c672' for '/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64': No such file or directory'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 75, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 2119, in _do_async_install
    guest.installer_instance.start_install(guest, meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/installer.py", line 419, in start_install
    doboot, transient)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/installer.py", line 362, in _create_guest
    domain = self.conn.createXML(install_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3717, in createXML
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed', conn=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: Process exited prior to exec: libvirt:  error : unable to set AppArmor profile 'libvirt-5d739005-01d9-4c7c-9b41-bb3e3486c672' for '/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64': No such file or directory
```

```bsh
➜ ls /usr/bin | grep qemu
qemu-img
qemu-io
qemu-nbd
qemu-pr-helper
qemu-system-i386
qemu-system-x86_64
qemu-system-x86_64-spice
```

Deleting the `AppArmor` profile files didn't seem to work.

Contents of `/etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/libvirt-af16e645-e650-48c4-93fc-7b11c2a885a1.files`

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY. IT IS MANAGED BY LIBVIRT.
  "/var/log/libvirt/**/win10.log" w,
  "/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-win10/monitor.sock" rw,
  "/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-3-win10/*" rw,
  "/var/run/libvirt/**/win10.pid" rwk,
  "/run/libvirt/**/win10.pid" rwk,
  "/var/run/libvirt/**/*.tunnelmigrate.dest.win10" rw,
  "/run/libvirt/**/*.tunnelmigrate.dest.win10" rw,
  "/var/lib/libvirt/images/win10.qcow2" rwk,
  "/home/ll931217/Downloads/Windows 10 Pro v.1709 En-US (64-bit) ACTiVATED-HOBBiT/Windows 10 Pro x64 En-US Activated.iso" rk,
  "/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd" rk,
  # don't audit writes to readonly files
  deny "/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd" w,
  "/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/win10_VARS.fd" rwk,
```

Contents of `/etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/libvirt-af16e645-e650-48c4-93fc-7b11c2a885a1`

```
#
# This profile is for the domain whose UUID matches this file.
#

#include <tunables/global>

profile libvirt-af16e645-e650-48c4-93fc-7b11c2a885a1 flags=(attach_disconnected) {
  #include <abstractions/libvirt-qemu>
  #include <libvirt/libvirt-af16e645-e650-48c4-93fc-7b11c2a885a1.files>

}
```

I had been searching since yesterday on Google to find the solution but I can't find anything on it. Does anyone here know why this error pops up?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a bug in some way and not something you are doing wrong. Listing your distro, libvirt, and qemu version might help. But might be able to work around it by disabling apparmor in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` with:

`security_driver = "none"`

And then restart libvirtd